# ruby string match ignore case

Tags: ruby, regex, string, case, match

I am trying to create a match query which selects text from a string between two words. I can't seem to figure out how to make the search case insensitive. 
For example consider the text:

```
contents = "cat
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec blandit feugiat mi, eu lacinia quam tincidunt eu. Donec eleifend adipiscing neque, in porta dolor vestibulum at. Curabitur id elit vitae nunc feugiat varius. Maecenas euismod euismod mi, eu blandit lectus.
dog"
```

the ruby code to return me the latin code between the words cat and dog is

```
contents.match(/cat(.*)dog/m)[1].strip
```

At the moment my "match" query only works if cat and dog are lowercase but I need to cater for if cat and dog are uppercase or the first letter is upper case.

Not quite sure where to stick the /i operator.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Next to the "m":

```
contents.match(/cat(.*)dog/im)[1].strip
```

Comment: I don't even think the "m" is doing anything in this expression. "m" is used to make `^` and `$` match the start/end of a line, rather than the start/end of input.

Comment: @d11wtq - I just tried it in irb and it seems to make a difference.  I believe it allows the . character to match newlines.

Comment: @coder_tim, ah, ok, I always use the `s` modifier for that ;)